# overwhelmed with test results

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tdd, vs-unit-testing-framework

I am getting a bit overwhelmed with number of test result files and directories being produced by Microsoft's own test framework (which comes with VS2010).

Does anyone know where to tell the test project not to save the results files or at least not keep so many?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tools -> Options -> Test Tools -> Test Execution

You can change the number of old test results files that are kept around. (25 is the default)